# cancelDraw io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate

Tags: flutter

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mZ5e4.png)

I am building an application on a physical device. Every time I start the app on my device I get this warning and I don't get any UI at all and I have a black screen. Do you know how can i fix this? The fixes I found didn't work.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.